# Return List<> values from model in view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return *Category names* in my `Index` view, from an already defined `List<CinematographyCategory_CinematographyModel>` in models.

When I call to return such names, it throws an exception, saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How can I get it to return the category names?

Here is my code from my project.

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">@item.ShortDescription</p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Title: </b>@item.Name</p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Genre: </b>@item.Genre.Name</p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Release year: </b>@item.ReleaseYear</p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Categories: </b>
@foreach ( var category in @item.CinematographyCategories_Cinematography )
{
      <div class="col text-start">
                @category.Category.Name // trying to return this, but throws an exception
      </div>
}
    </p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>IMDb score: </b>@item.IMDbScore</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class CinematographyModel : IEntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release year")]
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "IMDb score")]
    public double IMDbScore { get; set; }

    public List<Actor_CinematographyModel> Actors_Cinematography { get; set; }
    public List<Writer_CinematographyModel> Writers_Cinematography { get; set; }
    public List<CinematographyCategory_CinematographyModel> CinematographyCategories_Cinematography { get; set; }

    public int DirectorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DirectorID")]
    public DirectorModel Director { get; set; }

    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GenreID")]
    public CinematographyGenreModel Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class CinematographyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICinematographyService _service;

    public CinematographyController(ICinematographyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var allCinematography = await _service.GetAllAsync(n => n.Genre, m => m.CinematographyCategories_Cinematography);
        return View(allCinematography);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        var cinematographyDetails = await _service.GetCinematographyByIDAsync(id);
        return View(cinematographyDetails);
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Entity Base Repository, where I store all my general methods for easier access

```
public interface IEntityBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var result = await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();
            query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

Let me know, if anything else is needed, to fully understand what I am trying to do or how to get the result. Not exactly sure, how to make it pass list values to my view and have been stuck on this for a few days. Appreciate any help.

I tried to return specifically from my Cinematography model given Category names, but it just returns either the ID or system code. Also tried to modify methods, but with no luck.

**UPDATE**

It seems that for better understanding I should have included what exactly is `T` in Entity Base Repository context and where it comes from. Hope this helps.

Comment: Remove your "repository" code - it's an anti-pattern to use it with EF because it's redundant: `DbSet<T>` **is** a "repository" already.

Comment: Where is `T`  in `GetAllAsync()` coming from? You're missing your class declarations.

Comment: @Dai I see. For this project it is going to be kept as it is. Is the problem still fixable then?

Comment: I think you did not initialize `Actors_Cinematography` in  `public List<Actor_CinematographyModel> Actors_Cinematography { get; set; }`
  ... Besides, when you debug, your code should stop right at the line where it is a problem

Comment: @T.S. It is not a problem. In my other view `Actors_Cinematography` is able to retrieve correct actors for a specified movie, the same goes for `Writers_Cinematography` and `CinematographyCategories_Cinematography`. It is just that in my Index view, where I would like to show all of my cinema work data(movies, shows etc.), categories are not displaying.